# Braintree - 400 Bad Request Message on checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, http-request

I'm setting up Braintree payment In Magento 2 environment through integrated extension provided by Magento.

I have compiled the backend form with my merchant data and i selected sandox option to test all. 
All seems to work, Braintree payment option appear in my store frontend, I tried to do a payment with credit card datas provided by braintree, but when I click on checkout button, I receive this error message:

There was an error capturing the transaction: Please try again later.

If i debug the request with my browser developer tool I receive a 400 Bad Request response from this API:

http://MYSITE.SITE/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/XXXXXXX/payment-information

with this stack trace into the response request:

```
 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php(80): Magento\Braintree\Model\PaymentMethod->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), '101')
 n#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Processor.php(85): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\CaptureOperation->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
 n#2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(435): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
 n#3 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Interceptor.php(167): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
 n#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(341): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice))
 n#5 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/AbstractOperation.php(70): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice->capture()
 n#6 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php(30): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\AbstractOperation->invoice(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor))
 n#7 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Processor.php(85): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\CaptureOperation->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), NULL)
 n#8 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(435): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor->capture(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), NULL)
 n#9 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Interceptor.php(167): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->capture(NULL)
 n#10 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(416): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->capture(NULL)
 n#11 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(336): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->processAction('authorize_captu...', Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order))
 n#12 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Interceptor.php(154): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->place()
 n#13 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(871): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->place()
 n#14 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php(1060): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->_placePayment()
 n#15 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php(190): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->place()
 n#16 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(491): Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService->place(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order))
 n#17 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(394): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
 n#18 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php(354): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote))
 n#19 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartManagement.php(87): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder('12', NULL)
 n#20 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(79): Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement->placeOrder('99fb88573f13cc3...')
 n#21 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('99fb88573f13cc3...', 'alberto.gardena...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
 n#22 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(265): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
 n#23 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(160): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
 n#24 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 n#25 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 n#26 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
 n#27 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
 n#28 {main}
```

Has someone got the solution about this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem as well, but not with Braintree but just with the basic Bank transfer payment method. And only in production on in develop mode.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: have you cleared cache and generation folder ? 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Are you facing customer login issue along with this issue

Comment: hi @alberto i have faced the same issue while setup the braintree sandbox details please remove the merchant id and check it now. http://prntscr.com/fmow47

Answer (score 2):

I have tried in my local magento 2 and setup the **Braintree Sandbox** details.

**Please follow the below screenshots:**

**Admin end settings:**

[image: Admin end settings]

**Admin end settings:**

[image: Admin end settings]
**Onestep checkout page :**

[image: Onestep checkout page]

**After place order processing :**

[image: After place order processing]

**Success page**:
[image: Success page]

**Order view admin end :**

[image: Order view admin end]
**Transaction details in the braintree site :**

[image]

**Note:** When we give specify the **merchant id** in the admin end, it shows **bad request error** in the frontend.